# Uploading data and files in one form using Ajax PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery and Ajax for my forms to submit data and files but I'm not sure how to send both data and files in one form?

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="first" value="Bob" />
<input type="text" name="middle" value="James" />
<input type="text" name="last" value="Smith" />
<input name="image" type="file" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I was planning to use FormData as below

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

but figured out that it does not work in IE<10 and which is not accepted. Is there any other approach for same?

Answer (score 1):

This block should work for you.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#data').serializeArray(),
        error: function (a, b, c) { onError(a, b, c, parameters); },
        success: function (data) { onSuccess(data, parameters); }
    });
```

Comment: In C# asp.net , i used this. It worked for me. I caught the file in "HttpPostedFileBase" in controller. Find equivalent to this in php.

Comment: but i need it in PHP not C#

Answer (score 0):

```
function savedata(){

var vacancy_desc = CKEDITOR.instances['vacancy_desc'].getData();
   var file_data = $('#fileupload').prop('files')[0];  
   var form_data = new FormData();                  
   form_data.append('file', file_data);
   form_data.append('vacancy_records',vacancy_records);
   form_data.append('vacancy_desc',vacancy_desc);
$.ajax({
        url:pathname,
        method:"POST",
        dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:form_data,
        cache:false,
        success:function(datas){

                  alert('Updated successfully !');
                  return false;
            }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in php instead of using form data,

Serialize you form data and send through ajax, like,

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
        }
      });

    });
```

using `$('#form').serialize()` you can send your all form data to php.

I hope it helps,